# Validacion de caracteres

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando una calculadora a base de menús, el programa tiene 1 menú principal y 3 submenús, las variables en las que se leen las opciones ingresadas por el usuario son de tipo `int`, ahora bien, lo que necesito, es que si en el dado caso de que el usuario se equivoque e ingrese cualquier carácter, despliegue un mensaje de "opción invalida", y no me saque del programa sino que regrese al mismo menú.

A continuación pondré el menú principal y un submenú, ya que todo el código es algo extenso.

Tampoco incluiré las librerías, para ahorrar mas espacio.

```
int opc1, opc2, opc3, opc4;
bool Excepciones = false;
int main() {
do {
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t*-*-*- Menu Principal-*-*-*"<<endl<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[1]- Operaciones Basicas"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[2]- Operaciones Avanzadas"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[3]- Conversiones"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[4]- Salir del programa"<<endl<< endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t Elija la opcion: ";
    cin >> opc1;


    switch(opc1) {
        case 1: {
            system("cls");
            menuOpb();
            break;
            }
        case 2: {
            system("cls");
            menuOpa();
            break;
            }
        case 3: {
            system("cls");
            menuConversiones();
            break;
            }
        case 4: {
            Excepciones = true;
            break;
            }
        default:
            system("cls");
            cout <<"\n\n\t\t\t la opcion no existe"<<endl;
            system("pause>>cls");
            break;

        }
    }
   while(opc1 != 4);
   system("cls");
   cout<< "\n\n\n\t\t\t Saliendo del programa"<<endl;
   system("pause>>cls");
   return 0;
     }

void menuOpb() {
   do {
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t*-*-*- Menu Operaciones Basicas-*-*-*"<<endl<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[1]- Suma"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[2]- Resta"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[3]- Multiplicacion"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[4]- Division"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t[5]- Salir a menu principal"<<endl<< endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t Elija la opcion: ";
    cin >> opc2;



    switch(opc2) {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t -*-*-SUMA-*-*-"<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese primer numero: ";
            cin>>n1;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese segundo numero: ";
            cin>>n2;

            ptr = &n1;
            ptr2 = &n2;

            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t El resultado es: "<< *global(ptr,ptr2);
            system("pause>>cls");
            break;

        case 2:
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t -*-*-RESTA-*-*-"<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese primer numero: ";
            cin>>n1;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese segundo numero: ";
            cin>>n2;

            ptr = &n1;
            ptr2 = &n2;

            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t El resultado es: "<< *global(ptr,ptr2)<< endl;
            system("pause>>cls");
            break;

        case 3:
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t -*-*-MULTIPLICACION-*-*-"<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese primer numero: ";
            cin>>n1;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese segundo numero: ";
            cin>>n2;

            ptr = &n1;
            ptr2 = &n2;

            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t El resultado es: "<<*global(ptr,ptr2);
            system("pause>>cls");
            break;

        case 4:
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\t\t\t -*-*-DIVISION-*-*-"<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese primer numero: ";
            cin>>n1;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Ingrese segundo numero: ";
            cin>>n2;

            ptr = &n1;
            ptr2= &n2;

            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t El resultado es: "<< *global(ptr,ptr2);
            system("pause>>cls");
            break;

         case 5:
             Excepciones = false;
             break;

         default:
             system("cls");
             cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t La opcion elegida no existe...."<<endl;
             system("pause>>cls");
             break;

         }

     }
 while(opc2 != 5);

 system("cls");
 cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Saliendo al menu principal...."<< endl;
 system("pause>>cls");


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifica las condiciones del bucle `do-while` para que se repita mientras no se elija una opción válida:

```
void menuOpb() {
   do {

        // ...

        switch(opc2) {
            // ...
        }

     } while(opc2 < 1 || opc2 > 4); // <<--- AQUI!!!
 }
```

Si ya además evitas usar variables globales, tanto mejor:

```
void menuOpb() {

    int opcion = 0;
    do
    {

        // ...

        switch(opcion) {
            // ...
        }

     } while(opcion < 1 || opcion > 4);
 }
```

Comment: ahora bien, otro problema que tengo, es que cuando por ejemplo, si se ingresa 13, en lugar de marcar error, me ingresa a la opcion 1 del menu principal y la opcion 3 del primer sub menu, como hacer para que no haga eso???

Comment: @EmmanuelValdiviaRodriguez nuevas dudas = nueva pregunta. Algo has cambiado en el código porque no veo cómo reproducir ese comportamiento